# Sending sms through speech recognition

Tags: android-intent, sms

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:YOUR_SMS_NUMBER");   
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);   
intent.putExtra("sms_body", "The SMS text");   
startActivity(intent);
```

I'm new to Java and I'm making an app for sending an sms with speech recognition so I'm using this code

But it doesn't redirect me to the messaging app I have to open the messaging app myself and there the message is typed but I have to send it myself I want it to send the message as soon as it hears me say the hotword and I don't want it to redirect me to the messaging app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that might help you to resolve your issue

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromParts("sms", "mobilenumber", null));
intent.putExtra("sms_body","msg_to_send");
startActivity(new Intent());
```

Change "mobilenumber" to your desired contact number and "msg_to_send" to your desired message.

Comment: it is not working it just closes the app and takes me back to home screen

Comment: are there any error ? if yes then please help me with it so i could look into it

Comment: The code is fine but i need the app to call and send SMS to a constant recipient and with a constant body when the user says a certain hotword....(preset) i already have the calling feature but i don't have sms feature. Your code doesn't have any error but it disrupts the calling and also doesn't send the message. Please look into it and tell me also where to position the code you give me